# Sharing Python virtualenv environments

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have a Python virtualenv (created with virtualenvwerapper) in one user account.  I would like to use it from another user account on the same host.

How can I do this?
How can I set up virtual environments so as to be available to any user on the host?  (Primarily Linux / Debian but also Mac OSX.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put it in a user-neutral directory, and make it group-readable.

For instance, for libraries, I use `/srv/http/share/` for sharing code across web applications.

You could use `/usr/local/share/` for normal applications.

Comment: But what's the virtualenv / virtualenvwrapper syntax for using that directory?  With  virtualenvwrapper, the the command line << workon some_env >> looks for an environment in the user's .virtualenv directory.

Comment: What do you mean? You use `. bin/activate` as usual.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow.  When I switch into an environment, my command line is << workon some_env >> -- I don't touch bin/activate.

Comment: Now I get it.  1: Create environment w/ << virtualenv hothouse -p python2.7 >>.  This will create a directory for the environment in the working directory, with a subdir bin/ and script activate.  2: Use the environment with << source [absolute path to environment dir]/bin/activate >>.  With proper permissions, presto, the terminal environment now calls that virtualenv.  Leave with deactivate.  This same call works for environments created with virtualenvwrapper.  Thx.

Comment: @Flavius you just need to `sudo mv ~/.virtualenvs /usr/local/share`, `mkdir -p /usr/src/venv_projects/`, `chmod g+rwx /usr/local/share/.virtualenvs`, ` chmod g+rwx /usr/local/share/venv_projects` then edit your environment variables for `virtualenvwrapper` (usually in `.bashrc` before `source virtualenvwrapper.sh`). your new bashrc should have lines like `export PROJECT_HOME="/usr/src/venv"` and `export WORKON_HOME="/usr/src/venv`. Once you (or others in your group) log in (assuming they've put these lines in their bashrc too!) they can use the `workon` and `mkproject` commands as usual

Comment: ^^^ meant for @chernevik

Answer (score 11):

I had to do this for workmates. The @Flavius [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9506329/623735) worked great once I added a few commands to handle `virtualenvwrapper`. You need to put your venvs and your WORKON projects folder some place you and your boss/friend can find and use.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share
sudo mv ~/.virtualenvs /usr/local/share
sudo mkdir -p /usr/src/venv/
```

Assuming you want everyone on the machine to be able to both `mkproject` and `workon`:

```
chmod a+rwx /usr/local/share/.virtualenvs
chmod a+rwx /usr/src/venv
```

Otherwise `chown` and `chmod` to match your security requirements.

If you have any hooks or scripts that expect ~/.virtualenvs to be in the normal place, you better symlink it (on both your user account and your friend's)

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/.virtualenvs ~/.virtualenvs
```

Then modify your (**and your friend's**) `.bashrc` file to let virtualenvwrapper know where you moved things. Your bashrc should have something like this:

```
export PROJECT_HOME="/usr/src/venv/"
export WORKON_HOME="/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs"

export USR_BIN=$(dirname $(which virtualenv))
if [ -f $USR_BIN/virtualenvwrapper.sh ]; then
    source $USR_BIN/virtualenvwrapper.sh
else
    if [ -f /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh ]; then
        source /usr/bin/local/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    else
        echo "Can't find a virtualenv wrapper installation"
    fi  
fi
```

Once you log out and back in (or just `source ~/.bashrc` you should be good to go with commands like `mkproject awesome_new_python_project` and `workon awesome_new_python_project`.

As a bonus, add hooks to load the project folder in sublime every time your `workon`.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work (a module cannot be found when setting up as you suggested)—what is the role of `mkdir -p /usr/src/venv`—is that dir used for anything?

Comment: @pepe `/usr/src/venv` is probably unnecessary. I don't know why I originally did it that way.