# Sharing Virtualenv environment definitions

Tags: virtualenv

I have a heroku project I'm trying to share with someone else. As [the instructions describe](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django), I used virtualenv to manage the environment and dependencies. Is there a way to recreate the virtualenv configuration from the requirements.txt on a new machine?

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506281/sharing-python-virtualenv-environments), but that describes sharing the virtualenv between user accounts on the same machine. I'm looking for a way of sharing it across machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to easily fully share it across machines. The most convenient thing would be to create the virtualenv then re-install the dependencies fresh:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: `--no-site-packages` is now a default option