# How to create a shareable python install?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-module

Is there a way to have an easily shareable python install? I have a python install on my PC, and sometimes coworkers want to use and modify my code. To do so, they often need to replicate my python config. Is there a way I could easily share my config with them? From another angle, is there a way I could send my code so it can be run with a clean install of Python?

Comment: Use a [portable installation](http://portablepython.com/)?

Comment: Hum... Trying to get a sense of it through the documentation on the website... Not sure if I really understand how it works, but I will give it a try. We usually share things through an FTP server, so that would be great if I could all bundle it up in one zip file and send it to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jeff Mercado mentionned, [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/) is the way to go for me. I can zip my whole python install into one file and share it. It contains all the libraries I need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) ? I think it will meet your need to share your python environment after you have customized it to run your code.

Comment: It doesn't seem super easy to share the virtualenv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076292/sharing-virtualenv-environment-definitions ... I mean it is no different than using a normal python install as far as I am concerned.